# Color filling a shape using Turtle in Java

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I've been looking for a while now at how to fill a shape with a certain color using Turtle in java.
Let's say I have something like this:

```
private static void test(Turtle t1) {

    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        t1.fd(100);
        t1.right(90);
    }

}
```

Where `t1` is: `Turtle t1 = new Turtle();`

The code above creates a simple rectangle, and what I'm trying to figure out, is how to fill that rectangle with color (red, green, blue) . I've looked at the documentation in this [link](http://sites.asmsa.org/java-turtle/documentation) But so far I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use `t1.fillColor(Color.black);`?

Comment: When I try to use the method you suggested, it gives me an error saying it doesn't exist. @AlexCuadrón

Comment: I've obtained the method from the link in your question. I think it's better to override paintComponent(Graphics g){} when you're trying to draw things in Java.

Comment: @AlexCuadrón That requires learning Swing.

Comment: @OmerHen It sounds like the documentation you linked is for a different `Turtle` class than the one you are using.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice try [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) swing tutorial. It is going to be really helpful.

Comment: @AlexCuadrón I am not the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen more useful methods like `begin_fill` then *"do something"* and `end_fill` for *Turtle Graphics* in *Python* and it seems that the *Java* implementation works different but I believe I achieved what you need *(but I'm not sure if that's the best approach though)* but I agree with you, I couldn't find info about this plus, the methods described in the [link](http://sites.asmsa.org/java-turtle/documentation) that you provided are not the same as the ones from the *Turtle* object in the *Java* code. Why? because your *Turtle* object is using the `fd` method to move forward while the provided documentation says that there's a `forward` method to do so *(make sure you are using the correct library, in my case I'm using `jturtle-0.1.1.jar` and the methods are accurate to the code snippet from the OP)*.

***Java code:***

```
package com.turtle.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import ch.aplu.turtle.Turtle;

public class TurtleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Turtle turtle = new Turtle();

        // Init config
        turtle.setColor(Color.RED);
        turtle.setPenColor(Color.BLUE);
        turtle.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);

        // Draw rectangle
        for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
            turtle.fd(100);
            turtle.right(90);
        }

        // Fill rectangle
        turtle.fill(1, 1);
    }
}
```

So, when using the `fill` method *(which makes the trick)* you will see that there's one without parameters and another one expecting *X* and *Y* coordinates.

***Obtained from the Turtle class:***

```
  /** Fills the region the Turtle is in. 

  A Region is bounded by lines 
  of any other color than the background color and by the border of 
  the Window. <br>

  @return the turtle to allow chaining.
  */
  public Turtle fill(){
    getPlayground().fill(this);
    return this;
  }
  /** Fills the region with coordinates <code>x</code> and <code>y</code>. 

  A Region is bounded by lines 
  of any other color than the background color and by the border of 
  the Window. <br>

  @return the turtle to allow chaining.
  */
  public Turtle fill(double x, double y){
    double oldX = getX();
    double oldY = getY();
    boolean hidden = isHidden();
    ht().setPos(x,y);
    getPlayground().fill(this);
    setPos(oldX, oldY);
    if(!hidden){
      st();
    }
    return this;
  }
```

However, when I invoke just `fill()` it doesn't work but when specifying `X=1` and `Y=1` in the `fill(x, y)` method, it works *(could be good to debug the core methods to see what's going on?)* anyway, I didn't do it but when using above code, this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! @OscarJara and I do believe that further debugging of the core methods is necessary for me to really understand how this library works. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: I just have a small question, what do the `(x,y)` represent on in the `fill(double x, double y)` method? are they like the opposite points on the rectangle relative to the position of the turtle at the time? I didn't really understand what I need to plug in for the `x` and `y`

Comment: @OmerHen That's why I said that could be great to debug the core methods from the library, in other words, to debug what "fill" is doing in order to understand. Just set a breakpoint when "turtle.fill(...)" is invoked and step into.